# Ionic Framework 6 Admob

Tags: ionic-framework, admob, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

Reaching out the masses as at the loose end. I'm trying to integrate AdMob into my app. I've looked at the documentation on the ionic website and it points to a plugin that doesn't seem to want to install due to dependency issues. I've found a few other plugins too but again, they all seem to fail to install for the same reasons. I found one which has been updated the most recently of about 5 months ago but still the exact same issue [(this is the one)](https://github.com/admob-plus/admob-plus).

Does anyone know of any plugins which are working in Ionic Framework for Ad-Mob? Can I get away with a --force on installation and it will work?

Comment: You might want to share the install error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working in the end. It seems that a lot of the Ionic plugins are out of date. There is however a GitHub repo which contains a lot of the ones you need and it seems to be fairly well maintained.

https://github.com/capacitor-community